# store doesn't find non-installed applications

Tags: 16.04, ubuntu-store

I have just installed Ubuntu 16.04 and I noticed when I launched the store with no problem, it wasn't finding anything that wasn't already installed on the machine. Not Chromium, Steam, or anything. It just comes up with the nothing found screen like I typed in gibberish or something. I am connected to the internet and firefox does fully work.

Comment: No proxies or some weird network configuration?

Comment: Nope. The only thing I've messed with is the sources. I enabled all of them. Other than that, it's completely clean.

Comment: Did you try to install any package using apt? Did it work?

Comment: No, the machine flat out can't find packages.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like all the store needed was the machine to reboot. Its working now, although slow.